# I can't change the text and image size

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems changing the size of the text and the image in css. I'm just starting to use html and css. This is my code.

```js
function myFunction() {
          var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "https://vnwcn9gt89.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/book"; 
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           var myJson = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
           console.log(myJson);
           document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = myJson.Items[3].valore;
           document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = myJson.Items[1].valore;
           document.getElementById("img1").src="books_img/"+myJson.Items[0].valore;
          }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
        body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
        .img1 {display: none}
        img1 {vertical-align: middle;}

        .title {
          color: #333333;
          font-size: 3em;
          font-family: 40 px Olney,"Trebuchet MS",Tahoma,Arial,"Lucida Sans Unicode","Bitstream Vera Sans","DejaVu Sans",Sans-serif;
          font-weight: bold;
          padding: 8px 12px;
          position: static;
          bottom: 8px;
          width: 100%;
        }

        .text1 {
            color: #333333;
            padding: 8px 12px;
            font-family: 17 px Olney,"Trebuchet MS",Tahoma,Arial,"Lucida Sans Unicode","Bitstream Vera Sans","DejaVu Sans",Sans-serif;
        }

        .img1 {
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
```

```html
        <div>
        <h1 div class="title" id="title"  button onclick="myFunction()"></div> <br>
        <div class="text1" id="text1"  button onclick="myFunction()"></div> <br>
        <div class="img1"> <img id="img1" src onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src=myFunction();" style="width:50%"> </div>
        </div>

        <br>
```

In particular, I am unable to change the size of the text and I cannot center the image.
I definitely get confused with divs.
Can you kindly help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="text1" id="text1"  button onclick="myFunction()"></div> <br>
```

- For good practice, try using `<p>` for text.
  What happens is that you are trying to add `font-size` style to a `<div>`.
- You don't need to use `<br>` after a `<div>`.
- You can't use a button inside a div

The proposal solution is this:
CSS

```
.text {
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Olney,"Trebuchet MS",Tahoma,Arial,"Lucida Sans Unicode","Bitstream Vera Sans","DejaVu Sans",Sans-serif;
}

.text-container {
        padding: 8px 12px;
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="text-container">
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">
      <p class="text" id="text1"></p>
    </button>
  </div>
```

Now for the image, add text-align:center to img1:

```
.img1 {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Welcome to Programming :)

Answer (score 1):

1.) `font-family: 17 px Olney,` is not a valid definititon for font-size. Use `font-size` instead, and make sure to *not*  put a space between the number and "px".

2.)  To center your image, apply `text-align: center` to your `img1` class (which is the parent element of the image - the image itself is an inline element by default which can be centered that way)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the font-family property to set both the size and font-family of the text1 class. font-family property is used to set the font family only. So, use this

{font:17px Olney,"Trebuchet MS",Tahoma,Arial,"Lucida Sans Unicode","Bitstream Vera Sans","DejaVu Sans",Sans-serif;}

instead of font-family

Or you can specify the font-size and font-family separately like
{
font-size:17px;
font-family:"Trebuchet MS",Tahoma,Arial,"Lucida Sans Unicode","Bitstream Vera
Sans","DejaVu Sans",Sans-serif;
}

And if you want to set the width of the image to be 50% then you have to provide some width to the parent div of the image.